# Ubiquitous Encrypted Communication

Tags: encryption, email, gnupg, voip

What existing ubuntu applications exist to send encrypted communications using common technologies like email, chat and VOIP?

Comment: I've updated my post to refect my question more precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email: [Enigmail](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/enigmail) offers GNU PGP for Thunderbird.

Chat: [Cryptocat](https://crypto.cat/) and [Pidgin-Encryption](http://pidgin-encrypt.sourceforge.net/) provide encrypted chat.

VOIP: [F-Talk](http://ftalk.armanasci.com/guide/) gives encrypted VOIP.

Facebook and Gmail are a lost cause for privacy since if it's stored online in the US, the NSA can require the provider to cough up your data.

Comment: So essentially I have run encryption in the clients I use to access the services. I found sfphone for VOIP that I think will be better.